Creating Folders In Supabase
I'd like to have it so that I am able to create a folder in Supabase bucket with a specific name every time I run this function:
def create_storage(self):
        try:
            folder_path = f"/{self.company_id}/"
            # Supabase doesn't support creating empty folders, so we need to create a placeholder file
            result = self.storage_client.from_('productimages').upload(f"{folder_path}placeholder.txt", b"")

            if result:
                Logger.log(f"Storage folder created successfully: {folder_path}")
            else:
                Logger.log("Failed to create storage folder", level='error')
                raise Exception("Failed to create storage folder")

        except Exception as e:
            Logger.log(f"Error creating storage folder: {e}", level='error')
            raise

But I am running into an error of:
2024-05-28 06:33:22,186:ERROR - Error creating storage folder: {'statusCode': 400, 'error': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'new row violates row-level security policy'}
2024-05-28 06:33:22,186:ERROR - Error creating company: {'statusCode': 400, 'error': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'new row violates row-level security policy'}

What should I go about doing to resolve this and is it possible to change this?
I have tried updating the RLS policy on my bucket with:
BEGIN;
  ALTER POLICY "Allow Folder Upload rk11yf_0" ON "storage"."objects" WITH CHECK (auth.uid() IS NOT NULL);
COMMIT;

But It still does not work, any guidance on how to resolve would be appreciated.
